# BATCH - Preventing enter key spam

Tags: batch-file, spam

```
REM This is a sample code by me to illustrate my question

@echo off
:test
Echo Welcome %username%!
set /p T=Enter your text here
echo %username% : %T% >>C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Temp\xyz.txt
goto :test
```

The above one is a sample code by me which could help in illustrating my question.

In the above code, Once the user enters a message and presses enter key the message gets written in the file but there is a chance user may continuously press the 'Enter' key which would cause the same message to be return into the file. Is there any way I could prevent this from happening?

Thanks!

Comment: You should show your code, that would offer the possibility to understand your question

Comment: @Jeb I have added a sample code which would help in illustrating my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just pressing ENTER at `set /p` keeps the variable unchanged. So you have to clear it before:

```
@echo off
:test
Echo Welcome %username%!
set "T="
set /p T=Enter your text here
echo %username% : %T% >>C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Temp\xyz.txt
goto :test
```

if you don't want to log an empty entry, use Florians answer and replace
`echo %username% : %T% ...` with
`if not "%T%"=="" echo %username% : %T% ...` or
`if defined T echo %username% : %T% ...`

of course you could also predefine something other, like `set T=user didn't enter text"`

Answer (score 0):

```
  if not "%T%"=="" echo %username% : %T% >> xyz.txt
```

Update: removed ()

Comment: You need to place `set "T="` before `set /P`, otherwise `T` won't be empty if it has been set once before. And remove the parentheses! it might work stand-alone, but it won't work if the statement is placed within parentheses on its own...

Comment: Your syntax is wrong `IF not ("%T%=="")`. This can't work, as the parentheses would be part of the compared strings. Just remove them